# Remove newline from RShiny CSS SortableJS

Tags: css, r, shiny, sortablejs

I have a 99% working minimal example here. The only thing I would like to change is to have the rank number next to the letter rather than on the line above it.

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

addDiv <- function(x) {lapply(x,function(x){tags$div(x)})}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML('
      #rank_list_basic > div {cursor: move; #fallback
                        cursor: grab; cursor: pointer;}
      #rank_list_basic {list-style-type: none;  counter-reset: css-counter 0;}
      #rank_list_basic > div {counter-increment: css-counter 1;}
      #rank_list_basic > div:before {content: counter(css-counter) ". ";}
      ')
    )
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
            rank_list(
              text = "Drag the items in any desired order",
              labels = addDiv(c("A","B","C","D","E")),
              input_id = "output",
              css_id = "rank_list_basic"
            ),
          verbatimTextOutput("results_basic")
      )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$results_basic <- renderPrint({
    input$output
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply put your `labels` in a `list` instead of using `addDiv`:

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

addDiv <- function(x) {lapply(x,function(x){tags$div(x)})}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML('
      #rank_list_basic > div {cursor: move; #fallback
                        cursor: grab; cursor: pointer;}
      #rank_list_basic {list-style-type: none;  counter-reset: css-counter 0;}
      #rank_list_basic > div {counter-increment: css-counter 1;}
      #rank_list_basic > div:before {content: counter(css-counter) ". ";}
      ')
    )
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
    rank_list(
      text = "Drag the items in any desired order",
      labels = list("A","B","C","D","E"),
      input_id = "output",
      css_id = "rank_list_basic"
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("results_basic")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$results_basic <- renderPrint({
    input$output
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]